# Using semaphores to block a thread until all other threads have run a critical section a certain number of times

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'm writing a thread process using semaphores.

Given K, I want to be able to check if all previous threads have entered the critical section at least K-1 times. If not, the current thread would block until the previous threads have been able to do so.

Example: if you set K = 3, when the current thread wants to enter the critical section, it must check if all previous threads have entered the critical section K-1 (so twice in this case) times before it can enter the critical section

Does anyone know of a way in which I can implement this in Java? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the number of threads ahead of time?

Comment: Does this apply for all values of `K`?  So all threads should run once before any threads are run twice?

Comment: yes you can set the number of threads to any value of your choosing

Comment: yes essentially. so if you were to set K = 3, then all threads have to run twice before the next thread can run

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect the last comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are using Java 7 and use a [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).  The Phaser accomplishes this out of the box, where K-1 will be the phase.

Here is an example:

```
int waitForPhase = K-1;
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(n);
for(int i=0; i< n ;i++){
   e.submit(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
          for(j =0 ;j < waitForPhase ; j++){ 
              //do work
              phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
              // if you do not want all sub threads to wait for each
              // this can also be phaser.arrive() 
          }
       }
   });
}
phaser.awaitAdvance(waitForPhase);
```

So when starting there will be `n` registered parties in the phaser.  Each time one thread `arriveAndAwaitAdvance` it will wait until all threads reach that barrier.  Once all threads reach that barrier the phase will increment.  Once the phase reaches K-1 the invoking thread will break out.

After `phaser.awaitAdvance(waitForPhase);` your last statement is satisfied

> current thread would block until the previous threads have been able
>   to do so

Edit:

`awaitAdvance(int phase)` will suspend the current thread until the Phaser's current phase is the phase passed in as the argument.  Once all threads arrived and increments to the phase number passed in the current thread will be signaled to awake.

Comment: that makes sense. is there to do it without using Phaser. I haven't used a Phaser before so I'm not too familiar with what it does

Comment: You can use a CyclicBarrier but requires you to control the 'phase' yourself.

Comment: Question on phaser.awaitAdvance(waitForPhase): is that statement releasing the thread or what exactly does it mean